# Show local image inside html in webview when the device is offline in react-native

Tags: android, html, ios, react-native, webview

I have an articles that consists of different images across the page, those images are also stored locally on my device. When the device lose connection, there same article is shown as a locally stored html inside a webview, however the images are not loading (which makes sense), and the question would be - How to modify the html, so that when the device is offline instead of trying to fetch the images from the links, to point to the local images. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: please post the code for your html

Comment: https://pastebin.com/VLhPUNEm @Harrison

Answer (score 0):

`react-native-webview` allows you inject javascript, so all I did was edit your html and give your image an id called `myImage`. I created a functional state called `isOnline`, which when set to false passes the javascript function into the webview and displays the offline image that you want. To get the network connectivity state of your device, please refer to `react-native-community/netinfo` at  https://github.com/react-native-netinfo/react-native-netinfo. Style has been removed from your html for better reading so please inlcude it back in as needed.

```
export const MyWebViewComponent = () => {
    const WebViewRef
    const [isOnline, setIsOnline] = useState(false)
    const [placeholderImgSrc, setPlaceholderImgSrc] = useState(
        'https://hips.hearstapps.com/hmg-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/images/dog-puppy-on-garden-royalty-free-image-1586966191.jpg?crop=1.00xw:0.669xh;0,0.190xh&resize=1200:*'
    )
    useEffect(
        () => {
            if (!isOnline) {
                WebViewRef.injectJavaScript(
                    `(function(){  document.getElementById('myImage').src='${placeholderImgSrc}' })(); true;`
                ) //or simply do WebViewRef.injectJavaScript(`document.getElementById('myImage').src='${ placeholderImgSrc }'; true;`)
            }
        },
        [isOnline]
    )
    return (
        <View>
            <WebView ref={(ref) => (WebViewRef = ref)} style={{ flex: 1 }} originWhitelist={['*']} source={{ html: html }} />
        </View>
    )
}

const html = `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="contentdiv" class="article-content">

        <p><strong>text</strong>text</p> <br />
        <p><strong>text</strong> text</p> <br />
        <aside class="storyBoxout">
            <figure class="has-text">
                <div class="preview item"> 
                    <img id = "myImage" alt="" sizes="(max-width: 440px) 320px"
                        src="https://testlink.com/shimg/zx320y230c_4130819.jpg"
                        srcset="https://testlink.com/shimg/zx320y230c_4130819.jpg 320w, https://testlink.com/shimg/zx640y460c_4130819.jpg 640w">
                </div>
            <figcaption>
    </div>
    <script>
        
    </script>
</body>
</html>`
```